# Why php for loop can be run without counter?

Tags: php, for-loop

```
for( ; ; )
{echo 'hello';}
```

I'm a fresher PHP, hopefully someone can explain to this kind of question for me.Thanks.

Comment: its an infinite loop runs forever. Loops stop when condition is false, this loop has no condition so it runs forever. not something you want to do practically.

Answer (score 3):

From the PHP manual:

"*Each of the expressions can be empty or contain multiple expressions separated by commas. ... `expr2` being empty means the loop should be run indefinitely (PHP implicitly considers it as TRUE, like C).*"

There is a list of examples and `/* example 3 */` is an example of an "empty" for loop.

Read more/all on https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: PHP for loop needs to pass 3 expiration and they are separated by 2 semiclon "; ;" it can be empty or not